# I have a question from the Book of Leithold.

Tags: calculus

I have solved it but  i need a review for this problem. This is the question: Find an equation of the tangent to the curve $y=\frac{1}{3}x^2+2$ which is perpendicular to the line $x-y=0$. The statement in Portuguese is the same in English. the response of the book is $4x+4y-11=0$. What´s wrong with my solution?
May you see the question in this link. http://pt.scribd.com/doc/94701954/Questao-23-Leithold

Comment: Perpendicular to what line?

Comment: The question's lacking info.

Comment: I´m trying to typing in LaTex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reached $y=-x+\frac{11}{4}$. That is *equivalent* to the answer $4x+4y-11=0$ given in the book. Just multiply through by $4$ and bring everything over to the left-hand side.

I had a bit of a hard time with your question. The main problem is that you typed the question *incorrectly*. At this time, your question reads, in part,

"Find an equation of the tangent to the curve $y=\frac{1}{3}x^2+2$ which is perpendicular to the line $x-y=0$."

However, in your solution (in translation) the question reads

"Find an equation of the tangent to the curve $y=-\frac{1}{3}x^2+2$ which is perpendicular to the line $x-y=0$."

And indeed the answer corresponds to the choice $y=-\frac{1}{3}x^2+2$.

**What you should have done:**  Note that the slope of the line $x-y=0$ is $1$. Therefore the slope of any line perpendicular to $x-y=0$ is $-\frac{1}{1}$, which is $-1$. (If a line has $\ell$ has slope $m\ne 0$, then the slope of any line perpendicular to $\ell$ is $-\frac{1}{m}$.)

Now we calculate the slope of the tangent line to $y=-\frac{1}{3}x^2+2$ at the general point with coordinate $x$. We have $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2}{3}x$.

Thus we want $-\frac{2}{3}x=-1$, giving $x=\frac{3}{2}$.

If $x=\frac{3}{2}$, then the corresponding $y$ is $\frac{5}{4}$. Thus our tangent line has equation 
$$y-\frac{5}{4}=(-1)\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right).$$
This simplifies to your $y=-x+\frac{11}{4}$, and also to the answer in the book.

**Remark:** There are a number of mistakes in the handwritten solution that ou link to. These happen to cancel! For example, you end up setting $-\frac{2}{3}x$ equal to $1$ (not $-1$). Thus you end up with the wrong value of $x$. Later, a little sign slip cancels the mistake. I would urge you to look in detail at the solution given above.

Comment: Thanks André. I will see it more accurately.

Comment: @ViniciusL.Beserra: Please look at the modified answer. I decided that there must be a typo in your posted question. In any case, whatever the *real* question is, careful application of the technique I describe will always work.

Comment: This is right, about your answer in the handwriten solution.I will redo it. Thanks. After post the question here i realize that i should use the slpoe equals -1.